# typescript a recursive strongly typed function

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I'm really close, and sure that an experienced typescript developer would solve this really quick.

I want to create a function that receives an object, and an optional function to extend this object.

- if no argument is given - the object is returned.
- if extend function is given(given arg is different from `undefined`) - a new instance of this function with an updated initial object value is returned.
- the object is also optional. you override the current value of the object if you pass this object.

usage for example:

```js
let f1 = func(undefined, {'x': 10})
f1() // {x:10}
let f2 = func((pos: any) => ({...pos, y: 10}), {'x': 10})  //f2 => () => {x:number,y:number}
let f3 = f2()  //f3 is {x:10,y:10}
f3 // {x:10,y:10}
let f4 = f2((pos: any) => ({...pos, y: 10}),{})
f4() // {y:10}
```

javascript implementation:

```
function func(extend?, obj?) {
    if (extend) {
        let newObj = extend(obj)
        return ((extend, obj = newObj) => func(extend, obj))
    } else return obj
}
```

so far javascript results work great. so I want to create a typescript function that will follow the exact type of this object.

**solved thanks to @jcalz [see real usecase](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&ts=4.3.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgMEsB2NhQBmAhgMbBwDmwMACsTABYDKMDwAKgJ5jAA8HOAF44xHFwA0cANLC4AVxwATYIVzAlAPkQY4euAAoAlAC4ZAbl36%20AVU0HQ%20ZbQgBnM4pVqcGqWAaMAGKKpB7KqupKfm6s7GY2pjJwjsDKrgrh3hpwAPxwNnBm0pbo%20nC2UgCy9inObmFekX4BwTihhpDu%20UbC2pWJlSVlFXDVDiBOSi5dnhE%20UXD%20TK3tBp3xPUJ90a6x%20Btmg1Z6tjUTqVP1HTFs%203Acm9oJZtR0AXucPPw2UtKaQ9YfvkAExnSbTMxrG5xbq9EHNZYhBpzXyLaF3Z5UGj0Jgfbi8WzA37-Y7lIEANSqYIuEOuu1uwDMDzhlMWLSRdLM5Meo0SrxxLAZ%20P4rOqAJOFKp43BVyh9JhCRZCKCHLlXJ5lR2HwOWLeuKFXz4opJ6DQmHQpAgOFc8H57wZL2x9vYwr4Yi42hEhBCMCwVt1Ao%200ppbhyZndypWYdE4i1DpjXDkCGQPQQpKwhEMtUurlTpLKABsaHAfAB3aZybPTAxIAB09c6HxQonS7qM4rKcCgNHkUBwhjLAFFznVXFIywKVnIliq2lIAPoTtxyJe5uF2-XsAxDkc58fAcvsudwRcH6bt0nIZIF1wUNOlTt6DMdI%20kHrdmC9-szlZypvEVtxAvB9H2AG8KA-L80XlfAOzNM0MCLeAywAcSdJg5A3QUt1JOUeXvR89EgvtEDgeta06KQuDMABmAAGFA4IkXDOh5AADSo6IkBiABkABIEE6WsQGQCQAFoAEY6LYls4Eta0YGYkDSJAMwpJQDBgPk1wICLWsCwgShtwPNC9UYYwjEQ4tUPQxhgRXEzbIMFi3B5GsyIbNwpFU6DhLgABqOBgQYlMlLKPC4Q4rjeIEoSRPEqSZIAuSrRtJStNS3TgH0wzjNLUyBWBCyrOQxyzJohz8tsorOjhdzyMouAAC81JCowdkitjLPNJCSzKgUABZMNsoNaq2aCpFmLIFiQHz1JTEq%20qqsyAFZKoKgIBoMKammgzrZO0mBuqAA)**

---

### my own attempt

this is not a part of the question and it is only to show what I've already tried.

we will need to create a generic type function that returns a new generic if an arg given

```js
type Primitive = bigint | boolean | null | number | string | symbol | undefined;
type PlainObject = Record<string, Primitive>;

type genericFuncType<K extends PlainObject, Tin extends K=K, Tout extends Tin=Tin, T extends ((pos: Tin) => Tout) = undefined> = T extends undefined ? K: genericFuncType<Tout, Tout, Tout> 
let o = {x:10}
type ot = typeof o
to // {x: number}
type t1 = genericFuncType<ot>
t1 // {x: number}
type t2 = genericFuncType<ot,ot,ot,(pos:ot)=>ot>
t2 // a new function should be returned, but instead {x: number} is returned
```

well I couldn't make this generic work perfectly, but lets try it on the function, typescript `func` implementation:

```js
function func<K extends PlainObject, Tin extends K, Tout extends Tin, T extends ((pos: Tin) => Tout) = undefined>(extend: T, obj: K = {} as any): genericFuncType<K, Tin, Tout, T> {
    if (extend) {
        let newObj = extend(obj as any)
        return ((extend, obj = newObj) => func(extend,  obj)) as any
    } else return obj as any
}

let f1 = func(undefined, {'x': 10})  //f1 =>
typeof f1 // {x:number} - good
let f2 = func((pos: any) => ({...pos, y: 10}), {'x': 10})  //f2 => () => {x:number,y:number}
typeof f2 // {x:number} - bad
```

what I'm doing wrong? why I can't return a new function with extended type recursively?

(for reference only - [here's a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFARggcwQDtgoAfPAeyoBsIBDYiqYgV1tpfaVwjhYBnYImIEhIXnRZtiAEwgAzEhDkBuAFAQAHmCpwyoSLFoMSAeVwArCAGMyOAEp39cgDzDRBADSxEKNEwAPk0jaFwGQQRbGCpBKBwYUwtrOzINLV19MkVZewQqZgIIYBgGYAALAGVgcogACgBKAC4oTxICTR09Ayhc4nzCqGLS8ura4Ag3ADUoHUn5eIiomLjvDShNqAAVEjntBbl46fWtnao2MnmIRZ2SU63t-cP4+r1BVt3iRoSg88uHpttsQIAB3cyXZ43I7-YCAqDTEGgqG3aZBeobLbXeSxQQAflabzinxIPywf22FzhmM2YDGADE8gSoESPrCyX92mJ4e8anVmdMNC0WTSUXJcczWZ8qRydkiIdSznTKoyBpL3p95ZdZVyfKLeRMIAKkULyUwQJoNAB6ABUNo2NqgcDsEAwEHiTCgVDAaEKDC4-UGzGAVDFADooAhFKxQ9i5B0+nlfcxQZFhm7mM7gGw4MGKtA2GA5HU5FB3m1DRWvA6HW1kGB6FBQa42QAmL0+grED61yPRkAXKC2f1cSoIeKB5NN1AVKAMOAENhIG5kepUaOTrtQENioc552kMtxCt1H6oaecJ0lHPMBisMGR7u1AbQdfbirjxMDKegmdQQvFpMpbvGGvZRlAA5sEOI7vp+m5DL+lQxnOC5Liu8TnoIFQXLQpZZjec5VgmzpgM6ggrgmlTQAoUTOsBYx4JEqhenm0CmMIR6CHykygVA9p8VAAACdJwAwSBiriX5Bu+5RXrYrqYB6E4IHAHHzouy6HlRe5wAeZDKrOwh1L4Y4TkmW5YTheHXrm77QEiZYMUZky1sJ85iY5Kp5K5IkeQadQOlamQ9Dk5lDCMZSVNxUyzHGSyRNEuLwl8YrHMlVKpXcxDJZl9RSllsqUtqMjyEoKhyOicYSp8vgGaqtjqsS7K-ER3KcdFrSzDgADeAC+c4esQIA-N1orgfUVVxCNopnPQZBIpJOCTYI9TdWG63+ZM-VpuajSaGcZz4bZ9RIgAogc0JJfeoKRRU9UJJ5d15L4AD6C3Hjg72CLKEVjNFJ1gudhxXQtDLPVAb1grie2iv1EC0ORUCjQdWzjXVeQ-EdzDowMrLRQNc5DTDKObPDiNY+1hr7VsvUaLTwXZNu4DQL9UWGtszMPWEb6s+MdSWnN10AOIlLdD28-9oqsrKyMkxT3XaK0ACMAAMvggK0ADMKu9dTmy9fC0stQABgAsmrKtQAAMgAJN1IHaAbAC0qvG-C3Ua1Aqu0zDgtIiLoyVO2n1ggHt0YmcRvkkjM1bH7UMfUj61hu8tMk1e2a2V9etQAbUvvLKZsW9bdsO87rvrDDQA) for very similar function that works 2 levels deep - but nut recursively deep)

Comment: What actual practical ting are you expecting the generic to do? It sounds like you should just use `any`

Comment: I'm expecting typescript to follow the type of the given object over the different recursive instances of this function. `any` is just useless

Comment: But why? What does this achieve? Generics are only useful when you want to constrain types. You don't want to do that, you want to allow any type...so `any` is the right choice. It's much like using the base object in a strongly typed language, i.e. `object` in C#

Comment: Look at that function declaration: `function func<K extends PlainObject, Tin extends K, Tout extends Tin, T extends ((pos: Tin) => Tout) = undefined>(extend: T, obj: K = {} as any): genericFuncType<K, Tin, Tout, T>` do you not think that is a tad overly complex?

Comment: especially given that your function isn't very complex, the function declaration is bigger than the function! I think you're very much over-thinking this.

Comment: this is for an API for a library so I don't really care about the complexity as long as the user doesn't need to handle it by himself. i dont care to use generic or not, I just want that the object type would be strongly typed on different instances of this recursive fuction

Comment: As i said, this will be exposed as API and not for internal use. the requirement is that object type is statically available, is it possible using typescript?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237127/discussion-between-eliav-louski-and-liam).

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducable example. Make sure there are no errors in ts playground. Try to reduce your code as much as possible

Comment: i edited the reference playground, this is already simplified, this is not an easy task

Comment: If I try that usage example with your function implementation I immediately get a runtime error like `f1 is not a function`.  If I ignore that and try to give typings to the `func()` function JavaScript implementation, I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8drN).  If that meets your needs, I'll write up an answer.  Note that you can't pass in an `extend` like `(pos: any) => ({...pos, y: 10})`, which is of type `(pos: any) => any`... you'll just get `any` out; if you want the compiler to do something better, you need a generic like `<T>(pos: T) => ...`.

Comment: If it doesn't meet your needs, please try to remove any typos, errors, and extraneous stuff (does `Primitive` and `PlainObject` meaningfully contribute to the behavior here?  The fact that you're dealing with objects and not primitives seems like you could just remove that for the sake of the question; given your implementation.  For example, `func((x: number) => x + 1, 100)` should be fine), so that people who want to help can focus on the issue.

Comment: @jcalz hey thank you! that is eactly what I need, if you could write this as answer I would accept it!

Comment: I'd be happy to write an answer; would you mind cleaning up the question a bit so as not to have any code that would fail at runtime like `let f1 = func(undefined, {'x': 10}); f1()`?  Just make sure your example code is really showing what you're trying to do and not something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the implementation of `func()`, I think it would be best to make a `Func<T>` interface as an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) set of [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) which represents the four different ways you can call it or functions it returns (with or without each of the `extend` and `obj` parameters) and what the result should be.  A `Func<T>` is holding onto a result of type `T` that may or may not come out depending on how you call it:

```
interface Func<T extends object | undefined> {
  (): T;
  <U extends object>(extend: undefined, obj: U): U;
  <V extends object>(extend: (obj: T) => V): Func<V>;
  <U extends object, V extends object>(extend: (obj: U) => V, obj: U): Func<V>;
}
```

If you call a `Func<T>` with no `obj` argument, then it will operate on the value of type `T` that it's holding onto.  But if you call a `Func<T>` with an `obj` argument of type `U`, then it will operate on that `U` value instead of `T`.

If you call a `Func<T>` with no `extend` callback, then it will just return the value on which its operating; either `T` (if no `obj` is passed) or `U` (if `obj` is passed).

On the other hand if you call a `Func<T>` with an `extend` callback, that callback will be called on the value on which `Func<T>` is operating... so the `extend` callback either takes a `T` (if no `obj` is passed) or `U` (if `obj` is passed).  And whatever type `V` the `extend` callback returns, `Func<T>` will return another function of type `Func<V>`.

Finally, `func` itself is evidently a value of type `Func<undefined>`, since the value it is holding onto is just `undefined` (if you call `func()` with no arguments, you get `undefined` out).

That means we can write this:

```
const func: Func<undefined> = function func(extend?: any, obj?: any) {
  if (extend) {
    let newObj = extend(obj)
    return ((extend: any, obj = newObj) => func(extend, obj))
  } else return obj
}
```

Note that I've decided to use a lot of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) in the implementation since I'm not interested in convincing the compiler that `func` is actually a `Func<undefined>`.  I'm just claiming it is.

---

Okay, so let's see it in action:

```
let f1 = func(undefined, { 'x': 10 });
/* let f1: {
    x: number;
} */
console.log(f1.x.toFixed(2)) // "10.00"

let f2 = func(<T,>(pos: T) => ({ ...pos, y: 10 }), { 'x': 10 })
/* let f2: Func<{ x: number;} & { y: number;}> */
const f2r = f2();
/* const f2r: { x: number; } & { y: number; } */
console.log(f2r.y.toFixed(2)) // "10.00"
```

Looks good; the compiler understand exactly what is happening with `f1()` and `f2()`.

But there's an important note about how `f2` was produced.  The `extend` callback is of type `<T>(pos: T) => T & {y: number}`.  I had to annotate it as such  (or at least the input; the compiler could infer the return type).  This is necessary for the compiler to know that whatever is input as `pos`, a value of the same type with an extra numeric `y` property comes out.  If instead I just called `func()` with the callback as you had annotated it:

```
let f3 = func((pos: any) => ({ ...pos, y: 10 }), { 'x': 10 })
/* let f3: Func<any> */
const f3r = f3();
/* const f3r: any */
```

the compiler would infer that the return type of `extend` is just `any`, and `extend` is of type `(pos: any) => any`.  And once this happens it means that `f3` is a `Func<any>`, and the compiler has forgotten everything you cared about.  It's not really the compiler's fault, though; annotating things as `any` tends to do that; `any` is infectious that way.

And just to show that we can call the returned functions also:

```
let f4 = f2((pos) => ({ ...pos, y: 10 }), {});
//let f4: Func<{ y: number; }>

let f5 = f4()

// let f5: { y: number; }
console.log(JSON.stringify(f5)) // {"y":10}
```

Looks good!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcQIDwBVkQAekIAJgM7ID2ARgFYQJjIA+ympEMoEpAfMgDeAWABQyZAAoAlAC5kuANxiJ2AKoFiEMpVoMmfSURKl5HLj1IAaavXlq5yNcvHJsANU0nd9RmEPG2qZSevK40sgAvALujhhYHnwuqhqBOrb6YDaeaRQZfgFaZPKSoU4R0cjuNmUO8vE47kliAL5iYghUIOTMMJgI9f3Y5twgvAKRyH1YYMBdU-1GRaQA-PJwIACeNfRryBubESKuwDBSuUcqEsgANhDMYwDuAPL0UV5BpfTSVxJQ9+goCApEsTOstjs6O8nq86BUBNMEKCgpDpD9XC0CDdyCh-mBAcC9K12qJOt0qHcAHQ3KgAc0kiJk6LEd16AEZ3oyRpYbIJkAByQj8+RsgAMyBa0hcAHoAFS3e5TNnyY7XZCEeQgdAAWxo0BcmNl0o6XXIFIg1LpDLZlMIlLAVFQwEIvEkACY0chpdLkAAiMWU0Wi30k1lTN2cxZ4KyGAAOVHIYXhUj5lLT8fINk2IvFkt5AqFOYl6LlCt6bsGCT5GuQWt1+sxADIhMhs7WdXqoIoWgIjSbuuWoJy3TIZfKyT1w1AVerNR39RLkM2+W2653FIu+6TTebLfSYG6oJTNvbHc7XR6It6-QGgyHRKHFTAAMyRrCSSQZ8GHKICSSp9MEyzIs8xbQVhWQMVizEUswxfSscAOXtjW3AcpmfIdJhfUcYPHU1egw79kC3R9egAFmHD8M2Tf9kDTSkM2AyDc2kXlJRlaU4LIhDsBXOd6y7CU+FIqYAFZOTImQSWvODRJnVd50EtpULNKkaXpAApABlZ4ADlKR6KBQFpU5NgZUTPWvQRfU2X1ZDFFogA)

Comment: Thank you! Almost perfect, you can edit your answer to show that your answer works recursively (like the example usage in my questionl), it works you just did not mention it

Comment: Sure thing, although I've asked you at least twice to fix that code section so that it does not error out with `f1 is not a function`.  I'm trying to understand how that code relates to your `func()` implementation.  You write `//f3 is a function`, but it's not, because you created it by calling `f2()`, which spits out the held object and not another function. If I'm missing something obvious then please help me by editing that example code to something that actually runs with your JS implementation of `func`.

Comment: you are right! fixed! also see edit for real use case.thank you!

Comment: In that edit `f1()` still explodes things, and unfortunately that playground link seems to be misformatted, so [there's no real code in it](https://tsplay.dev/N7g9nN).  Still I can probably follow along enough to put that `f4()` in there.